# Multiple token to post on Facebook profile using php curl

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am trying get the below code to post on multiple Facebook accounts using an access token. I stored the access token in a file `token.txt` and I'm getting the access token from that `token.txt`file.

Here is my code:

```
$a = file_get_contents("token.txt");
$token = explode("\n",$a);
$data['message'] = "Hello Friends xoxo :)";
$data['access_token'] = $token;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Here is the output from the above code:

```
PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/masudtoo/public_html/mcteam/autopostfb.php on line 10
```

and this is the code on line 10:

```
$fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
```

The code has many problems. If you see any problems with the code, please try to help me fix it. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried running this code yet? Please add the errors that have been generated by running this code to the question. Thanks.

Comment: `PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /home/masudtoo/public_html/mcteam/autopostfb.php on line 10` and code line 10: ` $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';`

Comment: Thanks in the future please add this as part of the question 

Comment: i can't add this as part on my post

Comment: I just clicked the "edit" link below the question and was able to add it for you.

Comment: this message are coming `Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.` when i edit my post.

Comment: never seen that one, weird

Comment: Here is my new post: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47084892/how-to-update-status-on-multiple-facebook-account-using-multiple-access-token-wi`

Comment: You get that message because you are doing bad stuff. Stop doing bad stuff.

Comment: you may want to read the platform policy

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience.

Facebook does not permit auto-posting identical messages to a bunch of Facebook accounts/pages. What you're doing is (rightly) seen as spam and will get these accounts banned if you persist.

You should re-read the [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) and start following it.